# How to setup Kotlin on Android Studio?

Tags: kotlin

I have some troubles with the settings in Android Studio with Kotlin plugin? Someone can help me?
I follow the documentation guide on the official page https://kotlinlang.org/ , but have not effect.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you post what OS, Android Studio Version, KotlinVersion, etc. you tried to use. Also what “have no effect” means exactly… what did you try? what error message did you get? etc.

Comment: Try to follow [this](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/get-started.html) setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply  add in your gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

its will automatically ask syn gradle after that its showing to update kotlin setup then click   update its will automatically downloaded setup files from internet and updated automatically in android studio.

like build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.cricut.androidkotlin"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```